# Como realizar uma operação aritmética alterando inúmeros campos do banco de dados de forma eficiente?

Tags: python, postgresql, django

Existe uma tabela com 200 registros e um dos campos é responsável por indicar a ordem que esses dados são mostrados (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...). Preciso reorganizar esses dados, pegar o registro da posição 167 e colocar na posição 3, e obviamente o que estava na posição 3 irá para a posição 4, e 4 para o 5, e assim sucessivamente. O problema é que terei que alterar o campo "posição" dos 164 registros que tiveram a posição modificada. Há alguma forma eficiente de fazer isso? Ou terei que realizar um loop alterando cada registro individualmente? E se houver que reorganizar mais de um registro?

Obs: estou trabalhando com Python, PostgreSQL e Django

Comment: Faz tempo que não trabalho com Django. Nesse caso em específico, uma solução sql pura é mais que plausível. Vou checar aqui como faz isso no Django

Comment: Como é determinada a ordem? Qual é a chave da tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Fiz essa função no PostgreSQL que você pode usar, basta alterar para seus respectivos campos:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.reordenar (antiga integer,nova integer)
RETURNS boolean AS
$body$
declare
aux integer;
begin
aux := (Select pk from registros where ordem = $1 limit 1);

update registros set 
ordem = 
    case when $1 > $2 then 
        ordem + 1 
    else 
        ordem - 1 
    end  
where 
    case when $1 > $2 then
        ordem >= $2 and ordem <= $1 
    else
        ordem >= $1 and ordem <= $2
    end;

update registros set ordem = $2 where pk = aux;


return true;

end;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

Considerei que o campo de ordenação e a chave primária são do tipo `integer` e que não há repetição na ordenação mas também na há uma restrição quanto a duplicidade.

ps. Acredito que apenas a função no postgreSQL resolva seu problema, a parte do phyton ou django seria apenas para chamar a função.

Veja se lhe ajuda.

Comment: `django.db.connection` é a classe para fazer consultas diretas no banco, como essa chamada de função. Eu creio que dê para fazer em um único `update` essa operação, mas minha solução exige que eu esteja, digamos assim, sempre "movendo para trás", enquanto que a sua permite que se avance a posição do termo

Comment: Sim, basta executar um select:  `Select reordenar(167,3);` irá retornar um true apenas

Answer (score 0):

A questão aqui é pegar o item `n` e decrementar ele de `p`. No caso, os elementos do intervalo `[n - p, n)` precisam ser incrementados. Em SQL, essas duas operações de atualização seriam a seguinte atualização de valores:

```
UPDATE tabela
SET
    id = CASE WHEN id = n THEN n - p
            ELSE id + 1
            END
WHERE
    id >= n - p AND id <= n
```

Para chamar uma consulta de UPDATE diretamente do Django, estou usando [essa documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/) oficial.

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_update(n, p):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""UPDATE tabela
            SET
                id = CASE WHEN id = %s THEN %s
                        ELSE id + 1
                END
            WHERE
                id >= %s AND id <= %s
        """, [n, n - p, n - p, n])
```